# GTK_DEBUG not respected when using Python + Gtk+

Tags: python, gtk3, gobject-introspection

I am using Python 3.6 and Gtk+ 3.22.18 on macOS Sierra 10.12.4 (both Python and Gtk+ installed via Homebrew). I've found that neither the `GTK_DEBUG` environment variable, nor the `--gtk-debug` argument have any effect. However:

- They work for non-python apps, e.g. `GTK_DEBUG=modules gtk3-demo`
- `--gdk-debug` and other arguments do work
- Other environment variables are respected, e.g. `GTK_THEME`.

Only this doesn't work:

```
GTK_DEBUG=modules python hello.py
```

I'm pretty sure I'm using the same Gtk+ libraries for python and non-python apps. I've performed a search and only found one set of them.

I know Homebrew compiles Gtk+ with `--enable-debug=minimal`. To make sure that is not the culprit, I recompiled it without that flag, and can now use the Gtk inspector with `--gtk-debug=interactive` - but still only in C apps, not in Python apps. How can I use GTK_DEBUG?

Comment: Did you `export` `GTK_DEBUG`?

Comment: I've set it correctly. In bash either `GTK_DEBUG=interactive gtk3-demo` or `export GTK_DEBUG=interactive; gtk3-demo`. For good measure, I've tried both, but they do the same.

Comment: For me also it didn't work. But `GTK_DEBUG=interactive python3 myscript.py` works fine